# `Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/datatransport/TransportFactory` when using Xamarin.Firebase

Tags: c#, android, firebase, xamarin, maui

I'm creating a .NET MAUI application using the current preview 11.
When I tried to implement Push notifications I added the `Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging` package and just adding this package causes a crash when starting the app with the exception:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/datatransport/TransportFactory;
> at com.google.firebase.datatransport.TransportRegistrar.getComponents(TransportRegistrar.java:32)
> at com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRuntime.discoverComponents(ComponentRuntime.java:109)
> at com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRuntime.(ComponentRuntime.java:91)
> at com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRuntime.(ComponentRuntime.java:45)
> at com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRuntime$Builder.build(ComponentRuntime.java:360)
> at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.(FirebaseApp.java:427)
> at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(FirebaseApp.java:299)
> at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(FirebaseApp.java:267)
> at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(FirebaseApp.java:252)
> at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(FirebaseInitProvider.java:51)
> at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:2388)
> at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:2358)
> at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(FirebaseInitProvider.java:45)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:7239)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:6780)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6697)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:237)
> at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1913)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.datatransport.TransportFactory" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/.../base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/.../lib/x86_64, /data/app/.../base.apk!/lib/x86_64, /system/lib64, /system_ext/lib64]]
> at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:207)
> at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
> at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
> ... 24 more

During the build I get the following warnings:

> Warning in obj\Debug\net6.0-android\lp\153\jl\classes.jar:com/google/firebase/datatransport/TransportRegistrar.class:
> Type `com.google.android.datatransport.runtime.TransportRuntime` was not found, it is required for default or static interface methods desugaring of `Lcom/google/firebase/datatransport/TransportRegistrar;lambda$getComponents$0(Lcom/google/firebase/components/ComponentContainer;)Lcom/google/android/datatransport/TransportFactory;`

Via trail and error I found out this happens for all `Xamarin.Firebase.*` packages, but not when referencing e.g. `Xamarin.Google.Android.DataTransport.TransportRuntime` directly.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Were you able to figure this out? Having the same problem and the proposed solution below is not working for me.

Comment: @MattF: No, I still use the .2 versions

Answer (score 2):

I found a workaround:
Basically the newest version of the firebase packages are broken. Using the following packages worked:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Build.Download" Version="0.11.0" />
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup Condition="$(TargetFramework.Contains('-android'))">
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Google.Dagger" Version="2.39.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging" Version="122.0.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Base" Version="117.6.0.2" />
</ItemGroup>
```

As soon as I use the versions ending with `.3` instead of `.2` for the last two its broken...

Comment: The I got a lot of errors:   javac.exe error JAVAC0000:  error: package com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient does not exist